# How to assign work to each core on ARM Cortex A53?

Tags: kernel, arm64, osdev, microkernel

How to run 4 different functions separately on each core of ARM Cortex A53 *generally* (for cortex A53 CPUs at least, if possible) while using Aarch64 instruction set in kernel mode? I got User Manual for my CPU.

I am asking because of lack Internet Tutorials for kernel development for ARM cpus.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried everything I found - and really, I didn't find anything. I tried googlin "arm smp", "arm kernel thread", "arm multicore kernel tutorial" and so on, but all I got were pages like understanding smp, differences, basics and all these generalities. There is tons of tutorials and sources for developing kernel for x86 and I used few of them some time back, but I couldn't find anything for aarch64. All I want to know is few instructions to get all cores working. Thank you very much

Comment: There is **no general** way for start other ARM Cortex A53 cores. **Processor cannot start itself**. Loading cores is specific to concrete SoC (System on Chip). Take a manual describing you SoC (or *board*), and search this information in it.

Comment: Look into how an existing open-source kernel implements processor affinity for processes/threads.